# What advanced detection schemes can provide low cost screening for Latent Autoimmune Diabetes?

Tags: endocrinology, autoimmune-disease

[Latent Autoimmune Diabetes in Adults](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_autoimmune_diabetes_in_adults) (LADA) may be more prevalent than previously believed. A common marker for the most common form is glutamic acid decarboxylase 65 (GAD-65).

Are there low cost and sensitive tests for GAD-65 autoantibodies which might detect LADA earlier in life?